# CGContextSetShadow UITableViewCell performance

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, core-graphics, shadow

I'm using [ABTableViewCell from atebits](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) to customize UITableViewCell.

So in my subclass I'm overriding *drawContentView:* to do some drawing.

I'm drawing a rounded rect with a shadow, but scrolling is very slow because of the shadow. If I remove it, scrolling is fine.

Here is my code :

```
/// Fill cell color
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, __cgColorBCBEC1);
CGContextFillRects(context, &rect, 1);

/// Rounded rect
CGFloat radius = 5.0f;
__rrect.size.height = rect.size.height - 10.0f; // __rect represent my rounded CGRect
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, __rrect.origin.x, __rrect.origin.y + radius);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, __rrect.origin.x, __rrect.origin.y + __rrect.size.height - radius);
CGContextAddArc(context, __rrect.origin.x + radius, __rrect.origin.y + __rrect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI_4, M_PI_2, 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, __rrect.origin.x + __rrect.size.width - radius, __rrect.origin.y + __rrect.size.height);
CGContextAddArc(context, __rrect.origin.x + __rrect.size.width - radius, __rrect.origin.y + __rrect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI_2, 0.0f, 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, __rrect.origin.x + __rrect.size.width, __rrect.origin.y + radius);
CGContextAddArc(context, __rrect.origin.x + __rrect.size.width - radius, __rrect.origin.y + radius, radius, 0.0f, -M_PI_2, 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, __rrect.origin.x + radius, __rrect.origin.y);
CGContextAddArc(context, __rrect.origin.x + radius, __rrect.origin.y + radius, radius, -M_PI_2, M_PI, 1);

/// Set the shadow
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, __cgGreyColorF5);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, __zeroSize, 5.0f, __cgGreyColor33);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

/// Draw some text and a single line
```

What can I do to have good scrolling performances with the shadow ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get good scrolling performance with shadows and corner-radius and masks.
The only trick is sometimes you can simulate a shadow by adding an image on your desired place and make it overlay...